# Creating a Community Site or team site in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want to know how to create a community Site,  or Team Site in Sharepoint. I am able to create Pages, but I want to create a Community Site, which can be accessed by all. Could you please guide me with the steps? When I explore, I don t get the Create Site option. Should I have any special Access to create Site in sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You need to click SharePoint in APP laucher, you would get the Create Site option in that page.

Comment: I dont see that option in my Launcher. I just see Add new Post. Do I need to have any additional access ?